# Can I install OS's on a secondary hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, installation, computer-building

I'm going to build a new PC and thinking about getting a small 64GB SSD and then a 2TB hard drive. I want to run Hackintosh, Windows 7, and maybe Ubuntu on the SSD but I'm also thinking about FreeBSD and since I'd mainly be using Ubuntu, was wondering if I could install an OS on the 2TB hard drive instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bootloader must be on the primary drive, but most of the operating systems listed have no problem being installed proper on additional drives.